# Using protractor/jasmine angular e2e, how can I create a reusable suite of spec's

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor, e2e-testing

Below is the basic idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

suite.tmpl.js:

```
export default function(config) {
  describe('suite', function() {
    it('does something', function() {
      expect(config.items.length).toBe(config.mockedItems.length);
    });
};
```

something.spec.js

```
import getSomeData from 'here';
import suite from 'suite.tmpl';

fdescribe('the page', function() {
  let data, config, mockedItems = [1, 2, 3];

  describe('test', function() {

    getSomeData.then(result => data = result);

    config = {
      data: data,
      mockedItems: mockedItems
    };

    suite(config);
  });
});
```

The reason for this is I have many elements throughout the app using the same design and needing to copy tests all over the place.

How can I create a reusable set of tests?

Comment: Interesting approach +1 for q

Comment: You can use an ordinary function to describe common behaviors. This might help. http://pavelbogomolenko.github.io/dry-principles-with-protractor.html

Answer (score 1):

My example seems to work well as an additional layer of abstraction. Here's an example of my implementation...

suite.tmpl.js:

```
export default {
  suite: function(config) {
    describe('suite', function() {
      it('does something', function() {
        expect(config.data.length).toBe(config.mockedItems.length);
      });
    });
  }
};
```

something.spec.js

```
import something from 'here';
import tests from 'suite.tmpl';

describe('the page', function() {
  let data, config, mockedItems = [1, 2, 3];

  describe('suite', function() {

    something.then(result => data = result);

    config = {
      data: data,
      mockedItems: mockedItems
    };

    tests.suite(config);
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice approach, but when doing clever/non-standard things like this it's important that you/others can follow what's happening. Using good names and parameters can help. Something like reusableTests.checkLengthsMatch(data, mockedItems) nicely conveys what's happening.